# Is std::regex constructor safe?

Tags: c++

Just to make sure:
The constructors of `std::basic_regex` have to detect invalid expressions and throw an exception if it isn't correct. Right? So assuming I trust my STL implementer, I can pass arbitratry strings to it and I'll either get a valid regex object or an exception - no UB or something of that kind?

Does anyone know of buggy `std::basic_regex` implementations (EDIT: or other parts of the regex library) that are not robust against erroneous inputs?

Comment: That is what the documentation on `regex` states. However, no implementation is entirely bug free. Is there any particular implementation you are concerned about?

Comment: @P.W: Well, the usual ones like msvc, libstdc++ and libc++. Essentailly I'm wondering if it is fine to directly pass user data to it without any form of sanitization (not worried about security - just robustness)

Comment: libstdc++ does have issues: See one example: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86164

Comment: And so does libc++: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23017

Comment: Note that the last parameter in all five constructors that may be of interest in this case determines the regex grammar to use and defaults to ECMAScript.

Comment: @LafsiIronknuckles: Thanks for pointign that out. As long as it reliably tells me that the expression is invalid according to whatever grammar is specified I don't care all that much (only need very basic functionality) but I should definitely tell the user what grammar is accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the standard libraries do not have bugs (they do, as pointed out by P.W) there is a more general attack called ReDoS as described by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS):

> The Regular expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) is a Denial of Service attack, that exploits the fact that most Regular Expression implementations may reach extreme situations that cause them to work very slowly (exponentially related to input size). An attacker can then cause a program using a Regular Expression to enter these extreme situations and then hang for a very long time.

So I would at the very least limit the size of the allowed input so that your program cannot be DOS'd. Secondly, a general approach to test the robustness of the engine is through fuzzing. There are a variety of fuzzing libraries out there and some projects on GitHub that contain "naughty" strings that are explicitly meant for pen testing. You may find it worthwhile to fuzz the various engines to see where they fail.

Comment: Imposing some basic limits would certainly make sense. Although, as I mentioned in a comment, I'm not really interested in security. If the user (usually myself) wants to deliberately crash/slowdown the app, that is his prerogative ;).